# How can we synchronize MySql Database with Apache solr?

Tags: java, mysql, apache-kafka, solr, vert.x

I have java vertx web application which uses mysql as database also take apache kafka in use. To increase the speed of search query i was thinking to add apache solr in my application and store few tables in it.

But i m not able to find a way to keep those few table stored in mysql data in sync with apache solr.

i try to read DIH documentation but didnt found any solution

Comment: DIH has been removed from Solr core in 9.0 - so you're going to either have to depend on the community project or create an alternative way to index your content. Since you already have Kafka in your stack, could you detect when an object is updated through the queue, fetch it from MySQL and then index it to Solr? That would probably be the most scalable and best solution. If you want to do it with DIH, you're going to have to have a field that indicates that a row has been updated since it was last indexed (i.e. an updated_at field or a "has_been_indexed" that you set to FALSE when updating)

Comment: You might be interested in the conversation here: https://twitter.com/tsegismont/status/1585558218171899906